# How to wait for Autodesk installation to be completed when over the network?

Tags: batch, wait, mdt

The title may not be all that clear, but I'll do my best to explain better here:

Our company is using a bundle of Multi-Seat Standalone et Network licences for Autodesk Building Design Suite Premium 2015. Using the deployment tool supplied by Autodesk, I created deployment packages that are fully automated, to simplify our task.

Now, I am trying to use those same packages so they can be deployed using Microsoft Deployment Toolkit (MDT) platform, so that the software suite is deployed during our Windows installation on our computers.

Here is my batch file:

```
start /wait "" "\\slmtl-fs01.sidlee.inc\architecture\IMAGES\BDS_PM_2015\Img\Setup.exe" /qb /I \\slmtl-fs01.sidlee.inc\architecture\IMAGES\BDS_PM_2015\Img\BDS_PM_2015_NLM.ini /language en-us
```

This is the info from the installation shortcut created by Autodesk's deployment tool. I simply added the start /wait at the beginning.

From what I can gather, during the setup initialization, it will be using the network-based "Setup.exe" file, mentioned above. During this phase, some files will be copied into the local TEMP folder. Once the setup initialization is complete (making sure I have all the prerequisites, etc.), it seems as though the installation uses the local "Setup.exe" file, instead of the network one.

Is there a way to configure the batch file so that it waits for the "new" Setup.exe file instead of the network-based one ? Because right now, since the network-based Setup.exe file is being closed after initialization, Command Prompt thinks the installation is complete and skips to the next MDT installation/phase.

Let me know if my request is not clear.

Thank you :)

Comment: Can you try using PSexec to copy the files locally and then launch the installer locally? Does that help?

Comment: Ganesh: Doing a local install is not possible, considering the installation size is about 25 GB large, and has more than 100,000 files. It would take more than an hour just to copy it locally, then the installation time, then the deletion time! Hence why we're installing through the network.

Answer (score 0):

:: Adding this after your setup kick-off line should help:

```
:WAIT_FOR_INSTALL
REM Wait for 20 seconds:
ping -n 20 -w 1000 127.0.0.1 >NUL 2>&1

REM Check if setup.exe is still running
tasklist | find /i "setup.exe"  && goto WAIT_FOR_INSTALL
```